# Push Notification for UWP using Amazon SNS

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.forms, amazon-sns, xamarin.uwp, wns

We are developing a Xamarin UWP app that is supposed to receive Push Notifications using WNS. We are using Amazon SNS to send notifications. We made sure that the app is registering itself with proper channel URI to our backend, package name of the app is same as in the store and using Cognito credential put device token entry in  Amazon application arn. I have sent raw message to device endpoint and message received in device properly. We couldn't send as Json format and tried as mentioned in below link.

https://anbu2016.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/push-notification-with-wns-and-aws-sns/

But didn't know where to receive notification from application.

For example, ReceivedRemoteNotification as override method present in iOS and it will help process the notification. In my process sent argument then based an argument, we can navigate to different page. How can we do this in UWP using JSON format.

Please help me on this.

Regards,

Cheran